# Cannot Start Sentinel

Tags: redis, redis-sentinel

Getting below error when starting sentinel. anyone can help, please.

```
*** FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR ***
Reading the configuration file, at line 69
>>> 'sentinel monitor My_Master xx.xx.xxx.xxx 61010 2'
sentinel directive while not in sentinel mode
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a command line argument, i.e. *--sentinel*, to tell Redis to start in sentinel mode:

```
redis-server sentinel.conf --sentinel
```